# Auto-play sound on iphone

Tags: html, iphone, autoplay

I have developed an html countdown timer in web.
When the timer reaches 0 it should play a sound to buzz user.
So I need a auto-play sound, as I figured out the auto-play method removed on iPhone and iPad 
 What can I do? How can I play the sound?

Comment: Is it an app or is it something else?

Comment: Than you can't do anything I'm afraid. It is only possible by user interaction (click or something)

Comment: are you sure, no way?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play and immediately pause sound on any user click.
Then you can play it any time.
But only one sound or video.

Comment: any click? waht do you mean? could you explain more?

Comment: Go to: http://www.kurilo.su/iphone/test.html with iPhone
Touch Yes.
Wait five seconds.
All javascript you can see in html file.